# how to display page in full screen after using a frameset

Tags: html

Iam a web page that redirects you to the page **managersigning.html**

```
 <frameset rows="40%,*" noresize>
        <frame src="managerhomepage.jsp" name="actionwindow" noresize frameborder="0">
        <frame src="" name="resultwindow" frameborder="0">
 </frameset>
</html>
```

Now what ever the links i added in managerhomepage.jsp will be displayed in second frame since i used it as a target.

```
            <h2>MANAGER'S HOME PAGE</h2>
              <form> 
                <%String flag="ok";%>
                <a target="resultwindow" href="salesplan.jsp"><img src="images/salesplan.jpg"></a>
                <a target="resultwindow" href="managertracking.jsp"><img src="images/tracking.jpg"/></a>
                <a target="resultwindow" href=""><img src="images/reports.jpg"></a>
                <a  href="logoutpage.html"><img src="images/exit.jpg"/></a>
```

My problem is when ever exit button is clicked(last link ) it is displayed in the first frame since i didn't specified the target here. If i specified the target it will be displayed in second frame. But i want to display the **logoutpage.html** in entire screen instead of one of the frames. What to do..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `target="_top"` attribute in your link.  This will "break" out of the frames.

```
<a target="_top" href="logoutpage.html"><img src="images/exit.jpg"/></a>
```

FYI, most designers avoid frames - You can accomplish the same thing with a bit more work but no frames, and your users will thank you for it.

Comment: Thank you @Surreal Dreams for your answer and suggestion

Answer (score 1):

On your logout page link change it to this.

```
<a  href="logoutpage.html" target="_top"><img src="images/exit.jpg"/></a>
```

And you should be set